# Testing code that requires a Flask app or request context

Tags: python, flask

I am getting `working outside of request context` when trying to access `session` in a test.  How can I set up a context when I'm testing something that requires one?

```
import unittest
from flask import Flask, session

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    t = Test()
    hello = t.hello()
    return hello

class Test:
    def hello(self):
        session['h'] = 'hello'
        return session['h']

class MyUnitTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_unit(self):
        t = tests.Test()
        t.hello()
```

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/testing/

Answer (score 193, accepted):

If you want to make a request to your application, use the [`test_client`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/api/#flask.Flask.test_client).

```
c = app.test_client()
response = c.get('/test/url')
# test response
```

If you want to test code which uses an application context (`current_app`, `g`, `url_for`), push an [`app_context`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/api/#flask.Flask.app_context).

```
with app.app_context():
    # test your app context code
```

If you want test code which uses a request context (`request`, `session`), push a [`test_request_context`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/api/#flask.Flask.test_request_context).

```
with current_app.test_request_context():
    # test your request context code
```

---

Both app and request contexts can also be pushed manually, which is useful when using the interpreter.

```
>>> ctx = app.app_context()
>>> ctx.push()
```

Flask-Script or the new Flask cli will automatically push an app context when running the `shell` command.

---

[`Flask-Testing`](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Testing/) is a useful library that contains helpers for testing Flask apps.

Comment: Yep, i've wrapped the functions not routed nor related with Flask that needs request data to work ;) with `app_app.test_request_context():` and did worked.

Comment: Great summary of the different contexts (test, application, request).

Comment: FYI, here is the documentation for `app.test_request_context` https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/?highlight=test%20request%20context#flask.Flask.test_request_context.

Comment: Does c.get('/test/url') automatically create request and application context?

Comment: How difficult is it to put this in the Flask docs? Can't believe how difficult for me to land on this answer. Thank you very much!