# Flask Testing: Test App Request?

Tags: python, web, flask, flask-testing

While doing the Miguel Grinberg's Flask Web Development, I got stuck while testing the gravatar code,

```
def test_gravatar(self):
    u = User(email='john@example.com', password='cat')
    with self.app.test_request_context('/'):
        gravatar = u.gravatar()
        gravatar_256 = u.gravatar(size=256)
        gravatar_pg = u.gravatar(rating='pg')
        gravatar_retro = u.gravatar(default='retro')
    with self.app.test_request_context('/', base_url='https://example.com'):
        gravatar_ssl = u.gravatar()
    self.assertTrue('http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' +
                    'd4c74594d841139328695756648b6bd6'in gravatar)
    self.assertTrue('s=256' in gravatar_256)
    self.assertTrue('r=pg' in gravatar_pg)
    self.assertTrue('d=retro' in gravatar_retro)
    self.assertTrue('https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/' +
                    'd4c74594d841139328695756648b6bd6' in gravatar_ssl)
```

What does app.test_request_context() do and how is it different from app_context()?

Why do we even need to call with self.app.test_request_context('/')? Also, what changes can we do to shift the call to app.test_request_context() in SetUp()?

Answer (score 4):

There's plenty of reading to do on the subject, so start with the documentation: [`app_context`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.app_context), [`test_request_context`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.test_request_context), and you can always double-check the code: [`app_context`](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/1.0-maintenance/flask/app.py#L2188) and [`test_request_context`](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/1.0-maintenance/flask/app.py#L2225). In addition, [here's](http://kronosapiens.github.io/blog/2014/08/14/understanding-contexts-in-flask.html#the-application-context) an article discussion Flask's contexts.

That's a lot of links, so for a break-down:

We can see that `app_context` creates a new **application** context, while `test_request_context` creates a new **request** context. Application contexts are created in [two situations](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/appcontext/): manually with `app_context` and when a request context is created, which, in turn, is created with `test_request_context` or [at the beginning of the request](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/reqcontext/).

So when a [request comes into your application](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/reqcontext/#how-the-context-works), a **RequestContext** is created. The creation of this object creates an application context.

Why `test_request_context`? You need that *context* to access the application when working outside of a context created by a request, like [proxies](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/reqcontext/#notes-on-proxies) that you probably recognize, like [`current_app`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.current_app), [`request`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.request), [`g`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.g), and [`session`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.session). Going down into the code, when you create a RequestContext with `test_request_context` instead of [`request_context`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.request_context), you're getting a [`EnvironBuilder` object](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.15.x/test/#testing-api).

Answer (score 0):

Check out [tbicr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17375340/testing-code-that-requires-a-flask-app-or-request-context) 's answer here.

Specifically, this snippet of code

```
gravatar = u.gravatar()
gravatar_256 = u.gravatar(size=256)
gravatar_pg = u.gravatar(rating='pg')
gravatar_retro = u.gravatar(default='retro')
```

requires request context since it needs to access 'request' variable.

The definition of gravatar method in User Model needs 'request' variable.

```
def gravatar(self, size=100, default='identicon', rating='g'): 
        if request.is_secure: # here
            url = 'https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar' 
        else:  
            url = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar' 
        hash = self.avatar_hash or hashlib.md5(self.email.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest() 
        return '{url}/{hash}?s={size}&d={default}&r={rating}'.format(url=url, hash=hash, size=size, default=default, rating=rating)
```