# Flask / Eve: Internal GET request with parameters

Tags: python, flask, request, internal, eve

I am using a [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) webserver (part of an [eve](http://python-eve.org/) api) and need to do an internal `GET`-request.

For an external request I use this code:

```
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/simulations'
r = requests.get(url,
                 headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'},
                 params={'hateoas': False}
                 )
```

However, this is not working when trying to execute the request using the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module from a function within the flask app and raises an `ConnectionRefusedError`:

> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.',
>   ConnectionRefusedError(61, 'Connection refused'))

In order to make this [request available internally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17375340/getting-working-outside-of-request-context-error-when-accessing-session-during), I considered to use the [`test_client()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.test_client) of my flask application as follows:

```
r = app.test_client().get(url,
                          headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'}
                          )
```

This is working pretty well, but I need to pass additional parameters as you can see in my first sample snippet using the `requests` module. So I extended the code above to this:

```
r = app.test_client().get(url,
                          headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'},
                          params={'hateoas': False}
                          )
```

Unfortunately, this raises a `TypeError`:

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'params'

So is there a way to handle a `GET`-request either using flask or eve internally?

I know that there is a [`get_internal` repo branch](https://github.com/nicolaiarocci/eve/tree/get_internal/eve) for eve delivering a development implementation of `get_internal()` comparable to the other request types like `post_internal()`. But I do not like to use this development branch since it is not sure whether this feature would be implemented in the next stable release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you pass the query string is not right, you should:

```
r = app.test_client().get(url,
                          headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'},
                          query_string={'hateoas': False})
```

use the `query_string` keyword.

By the way, if you're posting, use the `data` keyword.

Comment: Besides my original question: Is there a way to get the response json-formatted?

Comment: You question don't have related code. But you can try `jsonify`.

Comment: I already tried this leading to a `Working outside of request context` error. However, I asked a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34241476/3991125) for this. Thanks a lot.