# RuntimeError: working outside of request context when trying to send POST request to Flask app from another python script

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I am trying to figure out how to send POST request to Flask app from another python script. But I am getting RuntimeError: **Working outside of request context**.

Here is my Flask app (`app.py`):

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask, jsonify, make_response, Response, request, json

def upload_data(file):
    df = pd.read_json(file)
    df['Res'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Res'], format="%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S")
    df['SQQ'] = np.nan
    return df

server = Flask(__name__)

@server.route('/results', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def DL_results_get():
    with server.test_request_context('/results'):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            reqData = request.get_json(force=True)
            df_DL = upload_data(reqData)
            return df_DL.to_json()
        else:
            return print('GET is not supported')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server.run(debug=True, port=85)
```

And here is my script for POST request (`request.py`):

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask, jsonify, make_response, Response, request, json

headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'}
dfDL = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
dfDLJson = dfDL.to_json()
myAuthResponse = request.post('http://0.0.0.0:85/results', headers=headers, data=dfDLJson)
dataReturned = json.loads(myAuthResponse.text)
print(dataReturned)
```

The error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "endpoint.test.py", line 12, in <module>
    myAuthResponse = request.post('http://0.0.0.0:85/DL-CA-results', headers=headers, data=dfDLJson)
  File "C:\Users\iakubal\Anaconda3\envs\general_3_6\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 347, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "C:\Users\iakubal\Anaconda3\envs\general_3_6\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 306, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "C:\Users\iakubal\Anaconda3\envs\general_3_6\lib\site-packages\flask\globals.py", line 38, in _lookup_req_object
    raise RuntimeError(_request_ctx_err_msg)
RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.
```

I've found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17375340/testing-code-that-requires-a-flask-app-or-request-context) and I tried to add `with server.test_request_context('/results')` into code for Flask app, but I still have the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use Flask's request in your python script, use the Python package called request as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733638/how-to-post-json-data-with-python-requests). You can install [requests](https://github.com/psf/requests) by

```
pip install requests
```

and use it like

```py
>>> import requests
>>> myAuthResponse = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/results', json=dfDLJson, headers=headers)
>>> myAuthResponse.status_code
200
>>> dataReturned = myAuthResponse.json()
```

Don't use Flask outside flask