# Test put request with mock using Flask in Python

Tags: python, flask, mocking, python-mock

I wrote this function using Flask in Python and it should work fine:

```py
from flask import request
import mysql.connector
from user import User
 def update_status(self, id):
        try:
            data = request.get_json()
            self.cursor.execute("UPDATE utenteflask SET status = %s WHERE id = %s", (data['status'], id))
            self.conn.commit()
            return "Status updated", 200
        except Exception as e:    
            print(f"Error: {str(e)}")
            return "Error occurred", 500
```

test:

```py
    @patch('flask.request')
    def test_update_status(self, mock_request):
        mock_cursor = Mock()
        mock_connect.return_value.cursor.return_value = mock_cursor
        user_id = 1  
        mock_request.get_json.return_value = {"status": "inactive"}
        result, status_code = self.api.update_status(user_id)
        self.assertEqual(status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(result, "Status updated")
```

but when I use monk in the test it gives me this error:

```py
    raise RuntimeError(unbound_message) from None
RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request. Consult the documentation on testing for  
information about how to avoid this problem.
```

Someone can help me?
Thank you!

Comment: The error has nothing to do with MySQL - please stop applying the MySQL tag. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68911496/5320906) and the answer it links to might give you some hints on how to fix this.