# How to preprocess function's argument to test its behavour when deployed to Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, python-requests, google-cloud-functions

When I create a Google Cloud function through Cloud Console, there is a default function:

```
def hello_world(request):
    """Responds to any HTTP request.
    Args:
        request (flask.Request): HTTP request object.
    Returns:
        The response text or any set of values that can be turned into a
        Response object using
        `make_response <http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.make_response>`.
    """
    request_json = request.get_json()
    if request.args and 'message' in request.args:
        return request.args.get('message')
    elif request_json and 'message' in request_json:
        return request_json['message']
    else:
        return f'Hello World!'
```

I would like to test this locally. When I deploy it, I will write this to my browser:

```
https://region-project.cloudfunctions.net/function-1?message={"a"=1,"b"=2}
```

To test `hello_world`, I need to pass it the dict I am passing to my function in the HTTP request above in some form. What is `processing`, if I expect `hello_world(processing({"a"=1,"b"=2}))` to output the same thing as a deployed Cloud Function would output to browser as a response to the request [https://region-project.cloudfunctions.net/function-1?message={"a"=1,"b"=2}](https://region-project.cloudfunctions.net/function-1?message=%7B%22a%22=1,%22b%22=2%7D)?

Answer (score 1):

The function body in Python for Cloud Functions is passed a Flask Request object (see [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#incoming-request-data)).  If you pass in an object that has a similar signature to the Request object you should be able to work.  There appears to be some documentation on testing flask apps found by a search on testing flask.  Examples include:

- [Testing code that requires a Flask app or request context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17375340/testing-code-that-requires-a-flask-app-or-request-context)
- [Testing Flask Applications](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/testing/)
- [Testing WSGI Applications](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/test/)