# How to test the python backend of a flask application?

Tags: python, flask

I have a draft of a flask application with a html/javascript frontend and a python backend, to which the frontend communicates through the flask API.

I want to test the python backend using the API using python only (no javascript etc involved in the testing). I found [this page](https://circleci.com/blog/testing-flask-framework-with-pytest/) with some suggestion but I guess something is missing.

I have tried the following test code in `tests/test1.py`:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

def test_1():
    """Example test"""
    response = app.test_client().get('/')
    print(response)
```

but the response returns a 404 error. I usually start the web server with `flask run --host 0.0.0.0` using this `server.py` script:

```
import sys
import json
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

from mf import gameplay

game = gameplay.Game()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('mainmap.html')

@app.route('/api', methods=['POST'])
def api():
    data_json = request.data.decode()
    data = json.loads(data_json)
    return game(data_json)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('0.0.0.0', 5000, threaded=True)
```

I guess I am missing something to start the test?

I found some examples [HERE](https://www.patricksoftwareblog.com/testing-a-flask-application-using-pytest/) and [HERE](https://testdriven.io/blog/flask-pytest/) that use something like

```
flask_app = create_app('flask_test.cfg')
```

but 1. `flask` does not have a method `create_app` and 2. what is the content of the config file (even not shown on the documentation of flask itself: [HERE](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/config/) ...???)? I did not find one example...

Comment: You are testing a new (empty) `app`. You have to import the real app.

Comment: And how do I do that?

Comment: Use the real app that you're creating in server.py instead of creating a new one.

Comment: How do I create the real app? What are the code lines? Ideally I start the backend server as one single server and use the tests on this one server (to have the same data in the backend )

Comment: I tried to use `app = Flask(__name__)
app.run('0.0.0.0', 5000, threaded=True)` before the tests but then no test is executed...

Comment: I also tried to use `app.create` but that does not seem to exist...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17375340/testing-code-that-requires-a-flask-app-or-request-context

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Testing code that requires a Flask app or request context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17375340/testing-code-that-requires-a-flask-app-or-request-context)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating a new application in your test module - meaning that you have no registered endpoints.

You'll need to import the `app` created in your `server` module.

`from your_package.server import app`

and use that as you're currently doing.

*Ideally* your server.py and your app.py are separate - meaning you have app.py with your app configuration and server.py imports the app required, and tests import the app required, so on and so forth.

Example:

`application.py`

```
import sys
import json
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

from mf import gameplay

game = gameplay.Game()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('mainmap.html')

@app.route('/api', methods=['POST'])
def api():
    data_json = request.data.decode()
    data = json.loads(data_json)
    return game(data_json)
```

`server.py`

```
from application import app
app.run('0.0.0.0', 5000, threaded=True)
```

`test.py`

```
from application import app

def test_1():
    """Example test"""
    with app.test_client() as client:
        response = client.get('/')
        print(response)
```

That should work!

Comment: Thanks for the explicit example, but when running this I get a 500 Server error... (I created the test file with the application definition in a single file)

Answer (score -1):

Forget `flask` for these tests! You start the server as usual, and then in your test code you make `request` calls like

```
import json, requests
r = requests.post('http://192.168.1.28:5000/api', data=json.dumps(data))
```

with whatever data (defined as a python dict). The URL is as defined in your python flask start script (the `http` is important, and no not end the path with a slash ("/")), and `api` is the interface you also define in the python flask start script.

Now you can make tests with a single running instance of your flask server!

Comment: `flask` provides you with what is needed to test an application. - You don't have to do that.

Comment: But nobody seems to know how. I am totally satisfied with my solution. It does not interfere with the  server at all and I know exactly what is going on.

Comment: You need context - I've left a comment in the question above - have a look there. - Once you provide context to the request you're doing, it should work just fine (:

Comment: Don't create a new app - import your original app from your setup.

Comment: from server import app

app.test..........

Comment: I tried the linked solution but I get a 500 server error. My solution still works! Why would I use a more complicated, hard-to-use solution?

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "importing the original(?) app from your setup". I have no idea ehat you mean by that! Does not make sense to me as the python startup script neither is a library nor a module I can import stuff frrom.

Comment: It's not complicated - I overlooked the fact that you're creating a new app and not importing the original app - thats your issue 99.9%. - should be as simple as importing the original app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252784/discussion-between-alex-and-julian-camilleri).