# Mocking Flask's request.get_json raises "RuntimeError: Working outside of request context" in unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

I develop unit tests for the backend of a large flask app. I am testing whether the helper function get_post_args() is handling empty requests correctly:

```
from flask import request
from unittest.mock import patch

from errors import NoPostArguments

def get_post_args() -> Dict[str, Any]:
    args = request.get_json()
    if not isinstance(args, dict):
        raise NoPostArguments(
            "no arguments given for this POST request; request not served"
        )
    return args


def test_get_post_args_returns_none():
    with patch(
        "request.get_json",
        return_value=None,
    ):
        with unittest.TestCase().assertRaises(NoPostArguments):
            get_post_args()
```

When I run this with pytest, I get the error:

```
test_get_post_args_returns_none failed: def test_get_post_args_returns_none():
>       with patch(
            "flask.request.get_json",
            return_value=None,
        ):

tests\unit_tests\test_arg_validation.py:243: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
..\..\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\unittest\mock.py:1438: in __enter__
    original, local = self.get_original()
..\..\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\unittest\mock.py:1401: in get_original
    original = target.__dict__[name]
venv02\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py:311: in __get__
    obj = instance._get_current_object()
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

    def _get_current_object() -> T:
        try:
            obj = local.get()
        except LookupError:
>           raise RuntimeError(unbound_message) from None
E           RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.
E           
E           This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
E           an active HTTP request. Consult the documentation on testing for
E           information about how to avoid this problem.

venv02\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py:508: RuntimeError
```

Any ideas on how to correctly mock request.get_json()?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Testing code that requires a Flask app or request context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17375340/testing-code-that-requires-a-flask-app-or-request-context)

Comment: @Dimitry no it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Flask provides you with [`app.test_request_context()`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#flask.Flask.test_request_context) method, which allows you to construct any kind of artificial request context you need. Mocking is an overkill in this case.

The simplest usage is:

```py
# Assuming you're inside a class derived from unittest.TestCase
def test_01_simplest(self):
    with your_app.test_request_context(method='POST', json={'message': "Hello!"}):
        result = get_post_args()
        self.assertIn('message', result)
```

An example to test catching `NoPostArguments` as `get_json` may not always result in a `dict`:

```py
def test_02_json_not_always_a_dict(self):
    with your_app.test_request_context(method='POST', json=[]), \
           self.assertRaises(NoPostArguments):
        get_post_args()
```

You may had trouble expressing empty json request. This can be done passing additional parameters defined for [`werkzeug.test.EnvironBuilder`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/test/#werkzeug.test.EnvironBuilder). As a side note, in this case `request.get_json()` will fail first and raise `werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequest`. So the proper test would look like this:

```py
import werkzeug.exceptions

...

def test_03_empty_json_payload(self):
    with your_app.test_request_context(method='POST',
                                       json=None,  # may be omitted
                                       content_type="application/json"), \
           self.assertRaises(werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequest):
        get_post_args()
```